# React not rendering classes on elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have two files, an `app.js` and an `index.html` and when I try to render a form with some CSS classes, the HTML elements display but the classes are missing.

This is my `app.js`:

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        alert('click')
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' name='list-name'/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Form/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

This is my HTML body:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="app" class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `class` can conflict with ECMAScript (it's a reserved keyword), React developers chose to use `className` as the attribute for HTML elements for classes instead of `class`. Per the React documentation:

> **Note**:
>   Since JSX is JavaScript, identifiers such as class and for are discouraged as XML attribute names. Instead, React DOM components expect DOM property names like className and htmlFor, respectively. [Source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Since `for` and `class` are reserved keywords of ECMAScript (of which JavaScript is an implementation), they cannot be used as XML attribute names. That means attributes of tags such as `div` or `input`.  Thus, use `className` to signify an HTML element's class. Here's an applicable example:

```
return (
    <div>
        <input className='form-control' type='text' name='list-name'/>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
    </div>
);
```

Notice that `className` is used in place of `class`.

Answer (score 4):

With react you have to use 'className' not class since class is a reserved JavaScript syntax.

Would be like div className="myclass"