# React not working with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, flask, gulp

I am starting a new project where I am using Flask + React + Bootstrap, but the Bootstrap within JSX is not working for some reason.

I am using gulp-react to transform JSX into JS.

Here is the JSX (literally an example from bootstrap website):

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
      </div>
    )}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

and the transformed JS:

```
var Example = React.createClass({displayName: "Example",
  render: function()  {
    return (
      React.createElement("div", {class: "input-group"}, 
        React.createElement("span", {class: "input-group-addon", id: "basic-addon1"}, "@"), 
        React.createElement("input", {type: "text", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username", "aria-describedby": "basic-addon1"})
      )
    )}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Example, null),
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

When I copy and paste the HTML into the HTML template, everything appears as expected. When I replace Example.render with a simple `<h1>Text</h1>`, it also renders fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React not rendering classes on elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442184/react-not-rendering-classes-on-elements)

Comment: You are using class instead of className.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we write JSX, we're still writing in JavaScript, just with some different syntax. In JavaScript 'class' is a keyword, which means we can't use 'class' unless we're actually trying to define one. So to work around this, you have to replace 'class' with 'className' as such:

```
var Example = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    return (
      <div className="input-group">
        <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
      </div>
    )}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

In your .html files, however, you wouldn't use 'className', it'd just be 'class' like you were trying to do originally.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but for some reason that did not fix the issue. Still, nothing is rendering.

Comment: Also make sure that you are including the Bootstrap stylesheet (either from a content distribution network (CDN) or a copy on your filesystem) in your HTML. I also forgot to change the first instance of 'class' to 'className'. So if you copied and pasted my code, that would have affected you

Comment: Just a simple question: Does your html `document` contain a element with the id `main`?